# P&T Checkboxes :total_selections Tag

Tags: pt-checkboxes

EE 2.10.1
P&T Fieldpack 2.2

Is the P&T Checkboxes [:total_selections Tag](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/fieldtypes/checkboxes/tags.html#total-selections-tag) supposed to work with Channel Form?

It's not working for me at the moment. The tag is not parsed.

Here is the code currently in use. This is enclosed in a basic Channel Form tag pair.

```
{options:field_name_here}   
<li>
<input type="checkbox" id="field_name_here" name="field_name_here[]" value="{option_value}"{checked}>    
<label class="checkbox">
{option_value}
</label>
</li> 
{/options:field_name_here}
```

The above works great. The following is just printed as is.

```
{field_name_here:total_selections}
```

Comment: Could you please expand? I've used P&T field pack all over the place, and without a template code sample, it's hard to see why you're having problems.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added more details. Geez, should have done that from the start.